# Konvajs filter fill transparent areas within image

Tags: konvajs

Is there a filter in konva that can fill closed transparent areas of the image with the white color?

[This is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9C4j.png)

[This is a target image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxZJ8.png)

I'm currently using konva custom filter for border. https://konvajs.github.io/docs/filters/Custom_Filter.html

```
var canvas, tempCanvas

function initBorderCanvas () {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
}

// make all pixells opaque 100% (except pixels that 100% transparent)
function removeTransparency (canvas) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  var nPixels = imageData.data.length
  for (var i = 3; i < nPixels; i += 4) {
    if (imageData.data[i] > 0) {
      imageData.data[i] = 255
    }
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
  return canvas
}

function Border (imageData) {
  var nPixels = imageData.data.length

  var ratio = this._cache.canvas.scene.pixelRatio
  var size = (this.getAttr('borderSize') || 0) * ratio

  if (size === 0) {
    return imageData
  }

  // - first set correct dimensions for canvases
  canvas.width = imageData.width
  canvas.height = imageData.height

  tempCanvas.width = imageData.width
  tempCanvas.height = imageData.height

  // - the draw original shape into temp canvas
  tempCanvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)

  // - then we need to remove alpha chanel, because it will affect shadow (transparent shapes has smaller shadow)
  removeTransparency(tempCanvas)

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  var color = this.getAttr('borderColor') || 'black'

  // 3. we will use shadow as border
  // so we just need apply shadow on the original image
  ctx.save()
  ctx.shadowColor = color
  ctx.shadowBlur = size
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0)
  ctx.restore()

  // - Then we will dive in into image data of [original image + shadow]
  // and remove transparency from shadow
  var tempImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  var SMOOTH_MIN_THRESHOLD = 0
  var SMOOTH_MAX_THRESHOLD = 0

  let val, hasValue

  var offset = 3

  for (var i = 3; i < nPixels; i += 4) {
    // skip opaque pixels
    if (imageData.data[i] === 255) {
      continue
    }

    val = tempImageData.data[i]
    hasValue = val !== 0
    if (!hasValue) {
      continue
    }
    if (val > SMOOTH_MAX_THRESHOLD) {
      val = 255
    } else if (val < SMOOTH_MIN_THRESHOLD) {
      val = 0
    } else {
      val =
        ((val - SMOOTH_MIN_THRESHOLD) /
          (SMOOTH_MAX_THRESHOLD - SMOOTH_MIN_THRESHOLD)) *
        255
    }
    tempImageData.data[i] = val
  }

  // draw resulted image (original + shadow without opacity) into canvas
  ctx.putImageData(tempImageData, 0, 0)

  // then fill whole image with color (after that shadow is colored)
  ctx.save()
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in'
  ctx.fillStyle = color
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.restore()

  // then we need to copy colored shadow into original imageData
  var newImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  var indexesToProcess = []
  for (var i = 3; i < nPixels; i += 4) {
    var hasTransparentOnTop =
      imageData.data[i - imageData.width * 4 * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnTopRight =
      imageData.data[i - (imageData.width * 4 + 4) * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnTopLeft =
      imageData.data[i - (imageData.width * 4 - 4) * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnRight = imageData.data[i + 4 * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnLeft = imageData.data[i - 4 * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnBottom =
      imageData.data[i + imageData.width * 4 * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnBottomRight =
      imageData.data[i + (imageData.width * 4 + 4) * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentOnBottomLeft =
      imageData.data[i + (imageData.width * 4 - 4) * offset] === 0
    var hasTransparentAround =
      hasTransparentOnTop ||
      hasTransparentOnRight ||
      hasTransparentOnLeft ||
      hasTransparentOnBottom ||
      hasTransparentOnTopRight ||
      hasTransparentOnTopLeft ||
      hasTransparentOnBottomRight ||
      hasTransparentOnBottomLeft

    // if pixel presented in original image - skip it
    // because we need to change only shadow area
    if (
      imageData.data[i] === 255 ||
      (imageData.data[i] && !hasTransparentAround)
    ) {
      continue
    }
    if (!newImageData.data[i]) {
      // skip transparent pixels
      continue
    }
    indexesToProcess.push(i)
  }

  for (var index = 0; index < indexesToProcess.length; index += 1) {
    var i = indexesToProcess[index]

    var alpha = imageData.data[i] / 255

    imageData.data[i] = newImageData.data[i]
    imageData.data[i - 1] =
      newImageData.data[i - 1] * (1 - alpha) + imageData.data[i - 1] * alpha
    imageData.data[i - 2] =
      newImageData.data[i - 2] * (1 - alpha) + imageData.data[i - 2] * alpha
    imageData.data[i - 3] =
      newImageData.data[i - 3] * (1 - alpha) + imageData.data[i - 3] * alpha
  }
}

export { initBorderCanvas, Border }
```

It does a good job on drawing a border around the image.

[Konva custom filter applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svzOC.png)

Is there a way to fill the circles as on target image?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecsy6hb4/34/

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ended up using https://github.com/sakri/MarchingSquaresJS. This is a algorithm to find a outline points. Once I got these I draw closed polygon and painted it inside. That solved my problem.

[Outline points example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkIlC.png)

These red points are the outline points returned by the marching squares algorithm.

fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ecsy6hb4/42/